# How can I use "gcov" even when a segmentation fault happens?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gcov

I'm compiling a C program with flags "-Wall -W -pedantic -O0 --coverage" (GCC version 4.8.2). However when a segmentation fault happens on that program I can't extract the coverage, because I don't have the .gcda file...

Does anyone know how can I use **gcov** even when a **segmentation fault happens**?

Thanks.

Comment: You need `-g` for the debug symbols, and you should use gdb, not gcov.

Comment: Hi @MatteoItalia, thanks for your reply, but I don't want debug the program, I want the coverage of an execution of the program (even when a segmentation fault happens). My question is similar to this old [question](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2012-04/msg00108.html).

Comment: Uh sorry, I completely misunderstood the question then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone know how can I use gcov even when a segmentation fault happens?

The coverage files are normally written by `atexit` handler, which requires program to call `exit()`. That does not happen when the program dies with `SIGSEGV`, which is why you don't get the `.gcda` file in that case.

The best solution is to fix whatever bug is causing `SIGSEGV` in the first place.

Alternatively, you could install a `SIGSEGV` handler, and call `exit()` from it. This is *not* guaranteed to work. For example, if your program hit `SIGSEGV` due to heap corruption, it may deadlock or crash *again* when `exit` calls global destructors.

Another possible solution is to run the program under GDB, and call `__gcov_flush()` from the debugger when you get `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: +1 Excellent - `__gcov_flush()` was exactly what I needed to know! Thank you!

Comment: I had no `__gcov_flush()` symbol in my context, but the idea worked. I simply called `gcov_exit()` (with a `print` command) and my executable wrote its `.gcda` files.